# ElasticSearch Sort on nested field across all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to sort based on nested field across all documents, for eg. in below JSON, fields is a nested object, what i am looking for is to retrieve all fields.name from all documents and then sort by name field. I know i can do this using inner hit query if it is part of single document.

The other option is to retrieve all documents and then do sorting on front end/middle tier which is not a good option.

```
[ {
          "id": "42ddf6e1-23f5-4aed-9d3a-1ba3ac3677b1",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "asofheading"
            },
            {
              "name": "SEC_TYPE"
            }
          ],
},
{
          "id": "7579928e-2196-4f7d-aaf8-4bfe9e67b330",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "asofheading"
            },
            {
              "name": "SEC_TYPE"
            },
            {
              "name": "CUSIP"
            }
          ]
 },
        {
          "id": "3a0940c1-7495-400c-a204-cd9bc6966fae",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "AsofHeading"
            },
            {
              "name": "SECT_PROFILE"
            },
            {
              "name": "SECT_PROFILESP"
            }
        },

]
```

I want to extract only field name from all documents and then sort by field name

Answer (score 9):

Use [nested sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting) (assuming the inner docs are of type [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/nested.html#_using_literal_nested_literal_fields_for_arrays_of_objects)).

So, for example, with the documents you provided:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "sort" : [
       {
          "fields.name" : {
             "mode" :  "max",
             "order" : "asc",
             "nested_path" : "fields"
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

returns:

```
{
   "took": 8,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "id": "7579928e-2196-4f7d-aaf8-4bfe9e67b330",
               "fields": [
                  {
                     "name": "asofheading"
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "SEC_TYPE"
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "CUSIP"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               "sec_type"
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "id": "42ddf6e1-23f5-4aed-9d3a-1ba3ac3677b1",
               "fields": [
                  {
                     "name": "asofheading"
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "SEC_TYPE"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               "sec_type"
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "id": "3a0940c1-7495-400c-a204-cd9bc6966fae",
               "fields": [
                  {
                     "name": "AsofHeading"
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "SECT_PROFILE"
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "SECT_PROFILESP"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               "sect_profilesp"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/2de98ca3e72663ce7af63c435deb5e85c6070088

Comment: Thanks Sloan for your quick response but I believe your solution is more geared towards sorting within single document and not across all documents, what i was looking out for a straight scoop where I can get field name in following order from all documents 
asofheading (from doc id 42ddf6e1-23f5-4aed-9d3a-1ba3ac3677b1)
asofheading (from doc id 42ddf6e1-23f5-4aed-9d3a-1ba3ac3677b1)
AsofHeading (from doc id 3a0940c1-7495-400c-a204-cd9bc6966fae)
CUSIP (from doc id 42ddf6e1-23f5-4aed-9d3a-1ba3ac3677b1)
SEC_TYPE
SEC_TYPE
SECT_PROFILE
SECT_PROFILESP

Comment: So you want a list of names returned? Then use a nested terms aggregation, sorted by term. But no, what I posted sorts the parent documents by (max or min) nested doc attributes, which is what your question sounded like it was asking for. It will do this across all the documents returned by the query, which in the case of what I posted is all (parent) documents.

Answer (score 5):

For recent version (6.8 here) the syntax has changed slightly (cf. [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting)), so it would now be:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "sort" : [
       {
          "fields.name" : {
             "mode" :  "max",
             "order" : "asc",
             "nested": { "path": "fields" }
          }
       }
    ]
}
```